# Mixed file types with CarrierWave

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

I've a CarrierWave uploader that shall accept a variety of file types. Some are image types (e.g. jpg, png) others are not.

I would like to create a medium version of the uploaded file with

```
version :medium do
  process :resize_to_fit => [300, 300]
end
```

As this only works for image files, how can I distinguish between images and other types and omit the resizing for non-image files?

At the moment CarrierWave tries to process the file regardless of it's type which leads to a MiniMagick processing error if the file is not an image.

Comment: You want to use this uploader for videos and audios too?

Comment: Yes. And PDF. And TXT. And EXE. And ZIP...

Comment: I never tried that but what if you check for uploading file extension before `version` block?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [Carrierwave Docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Do-conditional-processing) you can do the conditional processing:

```
version :medium, :if => :image? do
  process :resize_to_fit => [300, 300]
end

protected

def image?(new_file)
  new_file.content_type.include? 'image'
end
```

Actually more full answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344618/carrierwave-and-correct-file-extension-depending-on-its-contents)

Comment: Carrierwave uses the MimeType gem which determines its mime-type from the extension which poses a sucurity risk. If you upload a fake.jpg which in fact is a text file it will blow up. What's more your rails content type validations will never catch this edge case and allow text files to be uploaded as images.