# Carrierwave (with FOG) filename extension mismatch in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

I am uploading an audiofile and make a mp3 version, which works. Additionally I am generating a waveform out of the mp3 as a "png". Wich also works well.

The image was generated and saved but with "mp3" as suffix, which should be "png". 
The view has rendered the image correctly with the "mp3" fileextension name.

Now I get a 404 error when the view tries to get the image. The filename was not assumed correctly:

```
https://mybucket.amazonaws.com/uploads/sound/soundfile/142/waveform_Sky_02.wav
```

which should be

```
https://mybucket.amazonaws.com/uploads/sound/soundfile/142/waveform.png
```

here is my :version code:

```
 version :waveform do

    def filename
      "watermark.png" if original_filename.present?
    end

    def convert_to_waveform
      cache_stored_file! if !cached?
      Dir::Tmpname.create(File.basename(current_path)) do |tempname|
        begin
          puts system %Q{ffmpeg -y -i "#{current_path}" -f wav "#{tempname}" > /dev/null 2>&1}
          FileUtils.rm current_path
          Waveform.generate(tempname, current_path, method: :rms, background_color: :transparent)

        ensure
          FileUtils.rm tempname
        end
      end
    end

    process :convert_to_waveform

  end
```

The database saves "waveform_Sky_02.wav"

How can I get this working?

Comment: This has been answered very well here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344618/carrierwave-and-correct-file-extension-depending-on-its-contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has been working for me:

```
def full_filename(for_file=file)
  super.chomp('wav') + '.png'
end
```

or for all filetypes:

```
def full_filename(for_file=file)
  super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + '.png'
end
```